# Does this sentence have an adjective clause?

Tags: grammar

In the below sentence, is the part *the time of...* an adjective clause? If it is, why does it not have a relative pronoun? If it is not an adjective clause, what is the name of it?

> There it enters European literature around the thirteen-fifties, the time of Petrarch’s “Phisicke Against Fortune.”

Comment: It's a noun phrase in apposition to *the thirteen-fifties*.

Comment: For more information, see the comments to [Identifying Appositives and Nouns in Apposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384604/identifying-appositives-and-nouns-in-apposition). Note comments are subject to deletion at any time.

Comment: It can be considered a reduced relative clause of *which is the time of...*. See the answer by @Lawler [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/382413/210913)